# SQL Server : CAST(some_statement) - does some_statement know its inside CAST()?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, casting

I'm fairly new to SQL Server though I've worked with MySQL before.

Consider this statement

```
SELECT  
    CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE) AS currentdate 
FROM
    someTable;
```

In the above, does `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE` know that it's inside `CAST()`?

Now consider this statement

```
SELECT
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE 
FROM
    someTable;
```

The first one returns only the date, whereas the second one returns the complete time with date, time.

The question is, what happens when `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE` is inside `CAST()` versus otherwise

I do realize that AS DATE here means to rename the column as `DATE` on the resultant, but inside `CAST` it means completely different?

It's strange that `CAST()` or any other function can impact the implementation of the statements inside it.

For example, in Java if I have a method add(int a, int b), I can do add((2+2), (4+2)). So the statements inside the brackets will be compiled first and it will be sent as add(4, 6) to the method

Need more clarifications

Comment: Your first statement is casting the data type in a new format, then aliased as a column called currentdate. Your second statement is simply putting the current_timestamp in a column called DATE. The AS in the second case is an ALIAS, not an argument. Maybe this will help, in your first query the column inside the parenthesis has no name.

Comment: This is known as [Parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing). That is how the context of being inside `cast()` and not being inside `cast()` determines the meaning and outcome of each of your two statements.

Comment: It's strange how CAST() can impact the implementation of the statements inside it

Comment: CAST needs two arguments seperated by keyword "AS". It parses it and does what it does. SELECT can use a field and alias seperated by AS and it does something different. Like "smokin' read the paper to the class" vs "smokin' likes to read the paper to the class". Same words, different context, different meaning.

Comment: @smokin' Strange? Not really, that's the purpose of the function.

Comment: I think you are getting caught up in the syntax. The AS in the first statement does nothing except to identify DATE as a data type. It is required to parse the function. It is not aliasing the column even though the word is the same, the use is completely different.

Comment: @JNevill Oh that makes sense. AS is a separator between 2 arguments. This completely makes sense.

Its like 2+2 means 4 but here it's actually a separator so it'll separate both values instead of adding them. (Y) Thanks man!

Comment: Brainteaser. Try to guess what will happen if you do `select cast(current_timestamp as superdupername)`

Comment: @LukStorms Haha, just tried, it doesn't work. Says somedupername is not a defined system type. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly. CAST expects one of [these data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql) as an argument.

Comment: Or what about `SELECT CAST((SELECT current_timestamp as date from table) as date);` ;)  @smokin' That's probably the best way to think about it. "AS" as an operator like "+" that could mean adding or concatenate depending on the context. In this case the context is demanded by the function in which it's used.

Comment: @smokin' Just use ANSI standard and avoid the confusion... `NewColumnName = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)`

Comment: @JNevill Great answer, if you could write this as an answer I can mark it. Or I can answer it myself, whatever you like :)

Comment: Btw, [cast](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html) is also in MySql.  It's standard SQL.

Comment: @LukStorms Oh my!! you're right! I never knew it worked the same way.

Comment: @JNevill I understand that it's just the way it is, but I believe it would be easier if it were something else instead of AS, because AS is already used for identification. Better if it were a comma as it's already used every where to separate statements, column names, etc. But anyway, that's just how it is.

Comment: + is used for arithmetic and concatenation of strings as many other items have dual purpose. Also, `AS NewColumnName` isn't required... it's optional. You can just use `CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) newColumnName`... or again, ANSI standards as i commented above. AS in CAST isn't the oddball, using it in identification is the unique.

Comment: @scsimon Agreed, but I would just like to say, it shouldn't just be the same keyword for 2 purposes. This can be confusing.

Comment: Reusing keywords in multiple places with subtly (or not so subtly) different meanings is actually fairly common. Especially as languages evolve, language designers tend to opt for "lets reuse an existing keyword that people should already be avoiding" versus "lets introduce a new keyword and invalidate a lot of existing programs"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to JNevil for the clarification.

CAST needs two arguments seperated by keyword "AS". It parses it and does what it does. SELECT can use a field and alias seperated by AS and it does something different.

Probably the best way to think is, "AS" as an operator like "+" that could mean adding or concatenate depending on the context. In this case the context is demanded by the function in which it's used.

Such as 2+2 equals 4 but in a case where "+" is a separator itself, the statement 2+2 would just mean 2 different values instead of one value (addition's result)

The confusion only lies because "AS" is used in different contexts here.

Answer (score 0):

First one converts it into date datatype which does not have time attached.

Second one just assigns alias to current_timestamp with [Date] which will display as column name

Comment: I knew that already, but the actual problem was, how does CAST() change the implementation of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as DATE. cause I thought AS is always used an identifier. JNevill explained that CAST() takes 2 parameters and are separated by AS which then makes complete sense